# Delay popup 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, popover

I am using the following script to bring up a popover on my client's page. She has requested that it be delayed 60seconds. I am using `setTimeout` , but I'm having trouble implementing it. It is delaying `#mask`, but not `#boxes #dialog`

You can view the site here: http://www.julialucille.com/

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!
Here is my script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    setTimeout(function(){
        var id = '#dialog';

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     

        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.3); 
        $('#boxes #dialog').fadeTo("slow"); 

    }, 60000);

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {

        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: Aside from the implementation issues... please, please, _please_ strongly recommend to your client not to do this. As a site user it is so infuriating to have these obnoxious "sign up to my newsletter" popups suddenly appearing, especially when they completely take over what ever you were doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure both `#mask` and `#dialog` are both set to `display: none;` in the CSS, then use `setTimeout` according to the following script

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

  setTimeout(function(){
    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect  

    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.3); 
    $(id).fadeTo("slow", 1); 

  }, 30000);

  //if close button is clicked
  $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
  });

  //if mask is clicked
  $('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
  });

});
```